# How to connect to ConnectApi in visual studio

Tags: .net, connect-api

I am in Visual Studio 2015 and I can connect to Salesforce using the `Salesforce.Commmon`, `Salesforce.Force`, and `Salesforce.Chatter` namespaces, but I can not use the `ConnectApi` namespace shown [here, on salesforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_connect_api.htm). I have tried to connect to the API, but I cannot find any references that have helped me so far. Can someone explain to me what I have not done yet, and how I can connect?

[This is the salesforce toolkit I used to be able to use the `Salesforce.` directives](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2014/01/announcing-the-salesforce-toolkits-for-net.html).

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ConnectAPI](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_connect_api.htm) documentation you linked to is for Apex. Note that it states:

> The ConnectApi namespace (also called Chatter in Apex) provides classes for accessing the same data available in Chatter REST API.

So, in short, the ConnectAPI that you see in Apex is another name for the Chatter API.

Since you are calling into Salesforce from .NET, you will be using the [Chatter REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/). This is what the [Force.com toolkit for .NET](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET) will by wrapping for you.

Most of what you want will be in the [ChatterToolkitForNET](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET/tree/master/src/ChatterToolkitForNET). On particular, the [ChatterClient](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET/blob/master/src/ChatterToolkitForNET/ChatterClient.cs) in the `Salesforce.Chatter` namespace.